# AWS.config.credentials returns null when using `serverless invoke local` command in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, serverless, aws-appsync

I'm trying to run my AWS Lambda functions locally in a NodeJS environment with `serverless invoke local [...]` (as per https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/invoke-local).

I keep getting error messages from appsync/graphql/apollo, stating: `"Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 403"`

While debugging I found that I get the following:
`appsync.js`:

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
console.log(AWS.config.credentials); // returns null
```

If I try to run the same file with `node appsync.js` then instead of `null`, `AWS.config.credentials` returns a valid credentials object (taken from my local `.aws/credentials` file.

So everything is where it should be, the only problem seems to be with the `serverless invoke local ...` function not allowing my `aws-sdk` package to access my `.aws/credentials` file.

How do I get `aws-sdk` to set `AWS.config.credentials`?

Answer (score 0):

So the workaround that I managed to get working was to:

- copy and paste my `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` from `.aws/credentials` into my `.env` file.
- Replace `credentials: AWS.config.credentials,` in my config object as follows:

```js
const appSyncClientConfig = {
  url: "https://xxxxxxxxx.appsync-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/graphql", // from AppSync console.
  region: "eu-west-2",
  auth: {
    type: AUTH_TYPE.AWS_IAM,
    // credentials: AWS.config.credentials, REPLACED THIS WITH THE BELOW
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: process.env.aws_access_key_id,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.aws_secret_access_key,
    },
  },
  offlineConfig: {
    keyPrefix: "public",
  },
  disableOffline: true,
};
```

Now it's working.